# MySql: Getting sum of a table by the id of its parent from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

Imagine this is my database's tables:

```
Table #1: Parent
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════╗
║Child_id  ║Primary key - AI ║ int   ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║parent_id ║Index-Forign_key ║ int   ║
║══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║title     ║        -        ║varchar║                   
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════╝
```

---

```
Table #2: Paid
╔══════════╦═════════════════╦═══════╗
║Paid_id   ║Primary key - AI ║ int   ║
╠══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║child_id  ║Index-Forign_key ║ int   ║
║══════════╬═════════════════╬═══════╣
║paid_price║        -        ║int    ║                   
╚══════════╩═════════════════╩═══════╝
```

---

Here are my tables value:

```
Table: parent (data)
╔══════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ Child_id ║parent_id ║ title ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 1        ║25        ║bla-bla║
║══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 2        ║25        ║bla-bla║
║══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 3        ║5         ║bla-bla║
║══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ 4        ║25        ║bla-bla║
╚══════════╩══════════╩═══════╝

 Table: paid (data)
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ Paid_id  ║Child_id  ║ paid_price ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1        ║1         ║100         ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 2        ║2         ║250         ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 3        ║1         ║35          ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 4        ║1         ║17          ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

I have a query, but that does not work the way I wanted.

This is my query:

```
SELECT parent.Child_id, parent.parent_id,  SUM( paid_price )
FROM paid
JOIN parent ON parent.Child_id = paid.Child_id
WHERE parent.parent_id =25
```

This just return one row! But I want this return (get) all `child_id` from `parent` table, then by that ids return sum `paid_price` of each of them.

Now the query that I have just return:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ Child_id ║Parent_id ║ paid_price ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║ 1        ║25        ║152         ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

But as you can see `parent_id = 25` has some children, but the query that I wrote just return one of them (just the first one)! I want this return sum of `paid_price` of all that have `parent_id` number 25:

```
╔══════════╦══════════╦════════════╗
║ Child_id ║Parent_id ║ paid_price ║
╠══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║1         ║25        ║152         ║
║══════════╬══════════╬════════════╣
║2         ║25        ║250         ║
╚══════════╩══════════╩════════════╝
```

Please try query, I think it should be hard query to get what I need!

**How should I change the query to get the required result?**
(I think I should change whole my query)

Comment: I suspect the SUM() function, maybe?  Try adding `GROUP BY Child_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ALL non-aggregating columns in the group by clause (parent.Child_id, parent.parent_id). The reason you only got one row initially is because you had no group by clause at all.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5dfd7/5)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE parent
    (`Child_id` int, `parent_id` int, `title` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO parent
    (`Child_id`, `parent_id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (1, 25, 'bla-bla'),
    (2, 25, 'bla-bla'),
    (3, 5, 'bla-bla'),
    (4, 25, 'bla-bla')
;


CREATE TABLE paid
    (`Paid_id` int, `Child_id` int, `paid_price` int)
;

INSERT INTO paid
    (`Paid_id`, `Child_id`, `paid_price`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100),
    (2, 2, 250),
    (3, 1, 35),
    (4, 1, 17)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT parent.Child_id, parent.parent_id, sum(paid.paid_price)
FROM paid
JOIN parent ON parent.Child_id = paid.Child_id
WHERE parent.parent_id =25
group by parent.Child_id, parent.parent_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5dfd7/5/0)**:

```
| Child_id | parent_id | sum(paid.paid_price) |
|----------|-----------|----------------------|
|        1 |        25 |                  152 |
|        2 |        25 |                  250 |
```

Please note MySQL has a default server setting that permits "lazy" syntax when using GROUP BY. The unfortunate side effect of this is problems like this one. Always include ALL non-aggregating columns and you will avoid such issues. Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: You don't need to `GROUP BY` the parent ID and in fact your `WHERE` clause makes this extra grouping pointless.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen if you accept the default position in MySQL then yes you could avoid specifying all columns, however I NEVER do this because if the server setting is changed your GROUP BY clauses can fail. I simply adopt the practice that every other SQL db I know forces; include ALL non-aggregating columns, it's not hard and it works consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query was *almost* right, but it was missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT parent.Child_id, SUM(paid.paid_price) AS paid_price
FROM parent
INNER JOIN paid ON parent.Child_id = paid.Child_id
WHERE parent.parent_id = 25
GROUP BY paid.Child_id
```

Comment: Thanks, but this just return one row!

Comment: I think you have a problem with your data.  My query is fine.

Comment: Sorry, Yes you are right!   Thanks. your query is great and really is working well